# How to turn off automatically restart in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, reboot

When there is a memory problem, the computer may restart automatically instead of showing the blue screen. To avoid this on XP, I used to do the following:

```
Right click on "My Computer". 
Open "Properties". 
Click the advanced tab. 
Under "Startup and Recovery" click settings.
Uncheck the box next to "Automatically Restart" and click "OK"
```

But on Windows 7, there is not "My Computer". Under "Computer", there is not "Startup and Recovery" in the advance section.

How to I turn off "Automatically Restart" in Windows 7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd>
2. Select "Advanced system settings"
3. In the Advanced tab, click on the Settings button under "Startup and Recovery"

In the new window that opens, you will see the "Automatically restart" option.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on "Computer" in the start menu and select "properties" - in the left hand menu select "advanced system settings" - then you will know where you are.

Answer (score -2):

Here is simple steps to simply shutdown your computer after a specified time !!
[here](http://g.123.tn/how-to-shutdown-automatically-my-pc)

Comment: Please re-read the question, the OP wants to stop automatic restarts in the event of a problem